# Error while uploading Android .apk file to Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to upload my .apk file to Google Play market, but I get this error:

> Upload failed
>   Your APK cannot be analysed using 'aapt dump badging'. Error output: Failed to   run aapt dump badging: W/ResourceType(21292): Failure getting entry for 0x7f070000 (t=6 e=0) in package 0 (error -75) ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value

I have icon image inside drawable folder.

I had values-sr folder for some translation, but I deleted that folder because I don't need that translation now.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<supports-screens                                 
android:smallScreens="true"                    
android:normalScreens="true"         
android:largeScreens="true"            
android:xlargeScreens="true"             
android:anyDensity="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.LocalGameActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.ResultActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.TimedResultActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.RaceResultActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.RaceRankActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.OnlineRaceRankActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.OnlineRaceResultActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.SettingsActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.HelpActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Have u signed ur app ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're missing some string in ´values/strings.xml´ that you missed - `app_name`?. If you're using an IDE with android tools you could clean the project and rebuild it, that should clear the error or give you a pointer on what is wrong.